# Postman API testing: Unable to assert a value is true

Tags: postman

I am testing an API with a GET request that returns the following data:

```
    {
    "Verified": true,
    "VerifiedDate": 2018-10-08
}
```

I am trying to test that the first field comes back true, and the second field has a value. I have the following code:

```
    pm.test("Verified should be true", function () {
   var Status = pm.response.json();
   pm.expect(Status.Verified).to.be.true;
});

    pm.test("Returns a verified date", function () {
   var Status = pm.response.json();
   pm.expect(Status.VerifiedDate).to.not.eql(null);

});
```

The assert on true is failing for the following reason:

Verified should be true | AssertionError: expected undefined to be true

Why is the first test failing?

I am running the same test on a post command without any issues.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried logging the output to the console? Just to confirm that `pm.response.json()` is returning what you think it is?

Comment: Yeah but not all the values are returning.
What I have noticed is that it's not returning the data in a { } format, but [ {}], which I think means it's an array?

Comment: `var arr = pm.response.json();
console.log(arr.length)

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i].EIDVerified);
    console.log(arr[i].EIDVerifiedDate);
}`

Comment: This gives
null (well blank)
Expected date

Sorry this is posting over loads of comments, I've never posted anything before and I'm getting very confused!

Comment: Can you update the question with the full response body?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Root cause:**
Your result is an array but your test is verifying an object. Thus, the postman will throw the exception since it could not compare.

**Solution:**
Use exactly value of an item in the list with if else command to compare.

```
var arr = pm.response.json(); 
console.log(arr.length) 
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{ 
    if(arr[i].Verified === true){
        pm.test("Verified should be true", function () {
            pm.expect(arr[i].Verified).to.be.true;
        });
    }
    if(arr[i].Verified === false){
        pm.test("Verified should be false", function () {
            pm.expect(arr[i].Verified).to.be.false;
        });
    }     
}
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do this:

```
pm.test('Check the response body properties', () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json(), (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.Verified).to.be.true
        pm.expect(item.VerifiedDate).to.be.a('string').and.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/)
    })
})
```

The check will do a few things for you, it will iterate over the whole array and check that the `Verified` property is `true` and also check that the `VerifiedDate` is a string and matches the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, like in the example given in your question.

Comment: Thanks for you help peeps.